# Add data for existing users - Laravel

Tags: laravel, migration

I am adding a new table in my production application called `user_settings`. For all future users when registering it will create a new record. What is the best way to go about "seeding" the data for existing users?

Laravel docs say the seeders are for testing fake data.

So basically is there an industry standard for how to do this? Because all my existing users will need to have `user_settings` or the app won't work for them.

Ideas so far are:

- Add a query in the migration file that loops over all existing users after the table is created.
- Create a seeder and run it via the command line on the production server.
- The `->default()` option on the migrations won't work for me as it can change in time.

Comment: So basically you want to add a table of `user_settings` from a production server? You can just try to have a `->nullable()` and let the user change it if you dont want default.

Comment: @Jovs i think he wants add new whole table into production called user_settings

Comment: Yeah I think that too but I also think he want to do it in a running application with existing many data, and want to have a relationship with user to user_settings.

Comment: Basically I will have a default configuration for all users (`user_settings` table). Maybe something like:
- `user_id, user_display_name, user_dark_mode` etc

For new users when the create model event is fired I will create this related model `UserSettings` with settings from a default array. 

My question is what is the best way to go about doing this for users that exist in the database already. Like do I just loop over all existing users in the migration file and create the record from the same file as the migration?

Comment: `do I just loop over all existing users in the migration file and create the record from the same file as the migration` - that's what I've done in the past and it's worked for me.

Comment: `do I just loop over all existing users in the migration file and create the record from the same file as the migration` - that's what I've done in the past and it's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is write a migration to insert data into the table,

You will have to tweak the default migration file created,
This way your can then just run that migration on you production server as well to create data for existing users.

Heres an example.

```
public function up()
{
// Create the table
Schema::create('users', function($table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('email', 255);
    $table->string('password', 64);
    $table->boolean('verified');
    $table->string('token', 255);
    $table->timestamps();
});

// Insert some stuff
DB::table('users')->insert(
    array(
        'email' => 'name@domain.com',
        'verified' => true
    )
);
```

}